# Ruby check if variable exists in a file

Tags: ruby

I have a text file of one word per line.

I want to check if a Ruby variable exists on any lines in that file.

`@username = John`

and in bannedwords.txt:

```
Alex
Adam
Mary
John
James
```

So it would be true. What is the best function to use in Ruby for this?

Comment: To clarify, you have a blacklist text file. You want `return true` if some user input includes a blacklisted word?

Comment: What have you tried? You may want to show your code rather than expecting us to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read in the file and convert it to a `Set` you can use to test for inclusion:

```
require 'set'
banned = Set.new(File.readlines('bannedwords.txt').collect(&:chomp))

banned.include?('John')
# => true

banned.include?('Papa Smurf')
# => false
```

Answer (score 2):

`File.readlines("bannedwords.txt")` would return an array of names in your text file.

`.collect(&:chomp)` would strip the newlines from your array elements.

`.include?(@username)` would check if `@username` is in the array.

Putting all those together:

`File.readlines("bannedwords.txt").collect(&:chomp).include?(@username)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
File.read("path/to/bannedwords.txt").include?(@username).
```

Answer (score 0):

**The basic structure**:

What you're doing is checking if a value is in an array. Ignoring the loading of the file for the moment, this check is simple:

`bannedUsernames.include? username`

**The data**:

As for actually loading the file, you want to open the file, loop through the lines, and add each line to the array:

```
banned_usernames = [] # Empty array

# Open the file and assign it to the handle f
f = File.open("banned_usernames.txt")

# If this line doesn't make sense then read up on ruby blocks
f.each_line { |line| banned_usernames.push line }
```

Then just use the line from above to do your `if` statement:

```
if banned_usernames.include? username
```